# Cordova app running fine on safari, but crashing when installed as app

Tags: ios, css, cordova, memory-leaks

I've built a tool for a client, which basically is a tool that displays a number of items and filters them base on the set parameters. This tool started as a web-based project and it runs on all browsers and it should run when opening the html-file from the filebrowser(so when no server is involved).

We tested this on tablets/phones as we knew that it would needed to be ported. So this code is running fine on our ipad3(first gen retina) when we open it up on safari. Now we've been setting this up with cordova. But the moment this loads, we get memory warning, saying that the memory should be cleared etc... the app is running sluggish and some new bugs are showing, probably due to the memory issue's...

I've been looking into profiling/timelineing to find memory-leaks etc, but i can't really find any notable memory-leaks. 
Another quirky thing: If we build this app in portrait mode only, the issue's dissapear. But the code that is being executed is exactly the same, we don't do anything differently when in portrait mode besides other styling.

Could be CSS/Mediaqueries/images(png's) be causing these issue's? 
If anyone could point me in a direction, that would be great.

If you guys need code/examples/... shout and I will provide.
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue last week. Apparently this was cause by my css. The results were shown as small items in a list of approx 60 items. And they had an on-hover/touch event that would flip the item. But the css that was adding the perspective/backfacing etc was causing memory issue's. I removed them, and everything was working perfectly.

I do still however wonder why this is causing issue's in Cordova, but not in native safari, I would presume that the same app with same code on the same browser would give the same performance .... But apparently there are some differences between a webview and the native safari app?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you installed a WkWebview plugin, Cordova will run your app in a UiWebview which has a lot of performance and memory issues that are not present in WkWebview.

Native safari uses WkWebview under the hood, which explains the performance and stability differences between your Cordova app and Safari.